# Meaning of 'defy' in "age-defying youthfulness"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I know what defy means; but since I'm trying to correctly translate that phrase, I want to know which sense of this verb I should be looking at.

I couldn't figure it out from [here](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/defy-ones-age-the-years).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation in your citation is fairly straightforward.

Suppose X looks far younger than his or her age. We might say

“The way X looks utterly defies age.

The phrase represents a personification of aging as a powerful person whose commands X has refused to obey.

The phrase can also be used in the context of a person who behaves in a way that is admired in the relatively young, but is unusual in those who are older.

> He is over 50, but still is playing professional football: no one has defied age as he has.

So the phrase you are asking about indicates some youthful attribute in someone that is quite unusual given the person’s chronological age.